# How to change color of my Item template at runtime

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, windows-store-apps

I want to change color of my grid at runtime and I showing this item template in gridview in the mainpage.xaml...here I have tried for it
This Item template is in StandardStyle.xaml ...

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="Standard250x250ItemTemplate">
    <Grid Name="grid1"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="370" Height="200">

        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="40"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition ></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Border  Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="0" Background="{StaticResource ListViewItemPlaceholderBackgroundThemeBrush}" Height="30">
            <!--<Image Source="{Binding Image}" Stretch="UniformToFill" AutomationProperties.Name="{Binding Title}"/>-->
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding ProjectName}"  FontSize="20" Foreground="#FFCBD3D4" Style="{StaticResource TitleTextStyle}" TextAlignment="Center"/>
        </Border>
        <StackPanel Name="spname" Width="Auto" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Orientation="Vertical"  Background="{StaticResource ListViewItemOverlayBackgroundThemeBrush}" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
            <TextBlock Text=" Project Code   "  FontSize="25" TextWrapping="NoWrap" Foreground="{StaticResource  ListViewItemOverlaySecondaryForegroundThemeBrush}" Height="50" Width="200" TextAlignment="Left" />
            <TextBlock Text=" ProjectManager"  FontSize="25" TextWrapping="NoWrap" Foreground="{StaticResource  ListViewItemOverlaySecondaryForegroundThemeBrush}" Height="50" Width="200"  TextAlignment="Left" />
            <TextBlock Text=" Project Status " FontSize="25" TextWrapping="NoWrap" Foreground="{StaticResource  ListViewItemOverlaySecondaryForegroundThemeBrush}" Height="50" Width="200"  TextAlignment="Left" />
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Name="sp1" Width="200" Orientation="Vertical" Grid.Column="1"  Grid.Row="1"  Background="{StaticResource ListViewItemOverlayBackgroundThemeBrush}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding ProjectCode}" FontSize="25" TextWrapping="NoWrap" Foreground="{StaticResource ListViewItemOverlaySecondaryForegroundThemeBrush}" Height="50" TextAlignment="Center" />
            <TextBlock  Text="{Binding ProjectManagerName}" FontSize="25" TextWrapping="NoWrap" Foreground="{StaticResource  ListViewItemOverlaySecondaryForegroundThemeBrush}" Height="50" TextAlignment="Center"  />
            <TextBlock x:Name="statusblock" Text="{Binding ProjectStatus}" FontSize="25" TextWrapping="NoWrap" Foreground="{StaticResource  ListViewItemOverlaySecondaryForegroundThemeBrush}" Height="50" TextAlignment="Center"  />
        </StackPanel>
        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            <VisualStateGroup  x:Name="CommonStates">
                <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                    <VisualTransition From="Normal" To="Colored"  GeneratedDuration="00:00:01"></VisualTransition>
                </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                <VisualState x:Name="Colored">
                    <Storyboard>
                        <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="grid1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" To="Red" >
                 </ColorAnimation>
                    </Storyboard>
                </VisualState>
            </VisualStateGroup>
        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using mvvm, I would bind the grid color to a property in the viewmodel, then you can change the color at any time via "code":

```
 private System.Windows.Media.Brush _foregroundColor = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.DarkSeaGreen;

  public System.Windows.Media.Brush ForegroundColor
    {
        get { return _foregroundColor; }
        set
        {
            _foregroundColor = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("ForegroundColor");
        }
    }
```

Make sure to implement iNotifyPropertyChanged to notify the UI of changes

here is the xaml

```
 <Grid Background="{Binding Path=ForegroundColor}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

If you'd want to change `Grid color` based on `some property` you have in `view-model`
you could also do something like...

```
<DataTemplate>
    ...
    <DataTemplate.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Status}" Value="Error">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" TargetName="grid1" />
        </DataTrigger>
    </DataTemplate.Triggers>
</DataTemplate>
```

Personally, I'd always bind to a 'status' kind of property.
And then use either `data trigger` or bind directly like `<Grid Foreground="{Binding Status, Converter=statusToColor}" />` and use a converter to 'translate'.

*(I'm not sure if you're actually after some sort of animation or was that just a trial-error ?)*